# What is webapi "self" resource in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I understand the difference between anonymous and token authentication but can't really understand what is "self" resource and how is it used.
Thank's)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self is used by customer user:

> Self is a special access used if you already have an authenticated session with the system. Self access enables a user to access resources they own. For example, GET /V1/customers/me fetches the logged-in customer's details. This is typically useful for JavaScript-based widgets.

ref: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/get-started/authentication/